# convertir y copiar un campo VARCHAR de fechas a formato fechas en campo DATE

Tags: java, mysql

necesito de otra colaboración, tengo una tabla llamada carritoprestamo la cual incluye un campo fechas donde guardo una continuidad de fechas pero al querer hacer una consulta entre fechas no me funciona a lo cual trate de convertir esos datos a formato fecha pero no me sale:

Las fechas son guardadas de esta manera ejemplo:

29/05/2021

30/05/2021

31/05/2021

```
SELECT SUM(pagos) AS pagos 
FROM carritoprestamo 
where (cast(fech0as as DATE)) BETWEEN '" + fecha1 + "' AND '" + fecha2 + "';
```

Intente de esta otra forma pero tampoco sirve:

```
SELECT SUM(pagos) AS pagos 
FROM carritoprestamo 
where (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN '" + fecha1 + "' AND '" + fecha2 + "'
```

Por lo que igual mejor me gustaría crear otro campo que se llamara fechasDate para ver si hay algún tipo de consulta donde jale las fechas del campo fechas y las copie al nuevo campo pero ya en formato fechas del tipo DATE, ya leí que si utilizo Timestamp tendría que guardar fecha y hora pero a mi lo único que me interesa es la fecha, será que me pueden ayudar en eso u optimizar mejor la consulta.

¡¡¡SOLUCIONADO!!!
Respuesta desde codigo JAVA:

```
public String obtenerSumaPrestamo(String fecha1, String fecha2,String folio) {
    return mySql.GetDataString("pagos", 
            "SELECT SUM(pagos) AS pagos FROM carritoprestamo where"
                    + " (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN '" + fecha1 + "' AND '" + fecha2 + "'"
                            + " AND folio LIKE '" + folio + "' AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Para preguntas sobre bases de datos, siempre será útil indicar: a) versión de la BD que usas -por si hay algo raro en esa versión que otros conozcan- y b) la definición de las tablas involucradas. No cuenta contarnos el chisme "la tabla está hecha con un campo fechas". Pon la definición exacta de la tabla (`CREATE TABLE xxx...`). Ya nos diste datos de prueba y falta que nos digas, con los registros de prueba, la salida esperada.

Comment: y que tal si cambias el estado like por estado in

Comment: muchas gracias por el dato, lo tomare en cuenta para futuras dudas y publicaciones.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos ya encontré solución y lo eh publicado, que tengan linda tarde!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución por si le sirve a alguien y no se fija en que se editan los post:

```
public String obtenerSumaPrestamo(String fecha1, String fecha2,String folio) {
    return mySql.GetDataString("pagos", 
            "SELECT SUM(pagos) AS pagos FROM carritoprestamo where"
                    + " (cast(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') as DATE)) BETWEEN '" + fecha1 + "' AND '" + fecha2 + "'"
                            + " AND folio LIKE '" + folio + "' AND (estado LIKE 'VIGENTE' OR estado LIKE 'VENCIDO');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si transformas los valores al formato correcto, el cambio de tipo de dato es transparente:

```
UPDATE carritoprestamo 
  SET fechas = concat_ws( '-'
                        , substring(fechas,7,4)
                        , substring(fechas,4,2)
                        , substring(fechas,1,2)
                        );
ALTER TABLE carritoprestamo MODIFY fechas DATE;
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo tomare en cuenta tu respuesta en cuanto quiera modificar mis varchar a DATE de todas formas ya encontré la respuesta y lo publicare en el original saludos y buen día!!!!

Comment: ¿Qué beneficio le ves tenerlo como cadena?

Comment: esque nada mas es para una tabla donde verifico las fechas pero apartir de la fecha de inicio de cobro entre la fecha actual asi saco lo que si esta pagado lo excluyo y lo que no que esta vencido o vigente dentro de el rango de días lo sumo para que cada que se vaya a registrar un pago te saque el total con el adeudo en dado caso que se quiera pagar lo atrasado y ponerse al corriente, ahorita esa lógica ando empleando ya veré si mas adelante la modifico. si hago un video y lo subo a youtube talvez me entiendan mas pero lo are mas adelante.

Comment: Explicas para qué, mas no el porqué. La intención era contrastar los beneficios (tal vez uno) contra varias ventajas, que ya debiste comenzar a ver por el problema que tienes. Si vas a hacer operaciones con fechas debes manejar formato de fechas; por lo tanto, cambiar el tipo no es opcional, sino obligatorio. En algún momento te verías forzado a hacerlo, esperemos que no sea después de hacer mucho código; entre más tardes, mas correcciones harás.